# Filter a dynamically fetched dropdown list using CoffeeScript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I recently inherited a project where some of the forms are using CoffeeScript to dynamically fetch and post data.  The CoffeeScript is dividing the forms by different questions.  The one question I am trying to manipulate involves having a dropdown list with options that are fetched dynamically by making an API call.

**CoffeeScript:**

```
 new QS.JBChoice
    name: 'PrimaryJob'
    questionText: 'What is your primary job (required)?'
    maximumSelectionSize: 1
    choiceID: 'Job_Choice'
    skipLogic: (context) -> JobSkip(context)
    validateLogic: (validator, context) -> JobValidate(validator, context, 'Primary Job Required')
    questionID: 16
```

When the form is rendered, a dropdown list appears with dynamically fetched data.  Now I want to take the data from this dropdown list and filter it so that only specific options appear.

It should be noted that each option for the Job Type has specific Integer Values that are fetched when making the API call.  I actually have code in place that will prevent this question from appearing if a specific value is selected.

**Skipping the question with CoffeeScript:**

```
 skipLogic: (context) -> JobSkipLogic(context)

 JobSkipLogic = (context) ->
if !context.answers.Jobs?
    return true
jobs = choiceAsideFrom(context.answers.Jobs, [100, 105, 110, 115])    
not jobs

choiceAsideFrom = (answer, choices) ->
    count = numOverlaps(answer, choices)
    answerCount = answer.split(',').length
    count != -1 && answerCount > 0 && count < answerCount
```

So as you can see, `Jobs` is identified by the codes that are passed within the custom `choiceAsideFrom` function above.

I want to know if there is a way I can use a similar method to filter these Job types by these identifiers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what exactly is going on here (i.e. not sure what `numOverlaps` is and I don't know what the `Job` model entails). But if you're looking for a method that will help you filter a list of `Jobs` by type identifiers, you've got a couple of options:

```
typeIdentifierToFilterBy = 42
# Something like lodash or underscore's filter method
jobsOfType = _.filter(listOfJobs, {type: typeIdentifierToFilterBy})

# Or the JavaScript Array filter method
jobsOfType = listOfJobs.filter((job)-> job.type is typeIdentifierToFilterBy)

# Or CoffeeScript comprehension
jobsOfType = (job for job in listOfJobs when job.type is typeIdentifierToFilterBy)
```

Not entirely sure of the exact question, but hopefully that helps.